# opencv 3.2 (python 3.4.3) with usbcam + raspberry pi 3

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, webcam, raspberry-pi3, debian-jessie

I am doing a project related to video streaming at client (**socket programming**) and I am getting two errors:

**Error 1:**

Many people talked about this error, But I am not able to get a clear view about this error - programming legends help me to solve this below error.

```
Corrupt JPEG data: 1 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd0
Corrupt JPEG data: 1 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd0
Corrupt JPEG data: 2 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd0
Corrupt JPEG data: 3 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd0
Corrupt JPEG data: 1 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd2
Corrupt JPEG data: 1 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd4
Corrupt JPEG data: 1 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd0
Corrupt JPEG data: 1 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd0
Corrupt JPEG data: 1 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd1
```

Even-though the above error is coming the output is good.
why this corrupt error comes and how to solve it and it is not affecting the stream - why?

**Error 2:**

[PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9I07e.jpg)

What the problem I am facing is, when I run my Server after successful run, it is showing the first run error (check my picture link-provided). After that error I just terminate the Server and re-run it it will work perfectly - this will repeat every time - why?

Once the Server started, it is perfect and the frame to client transfer won't stop till I terminate the server, and the Server won't be getting terminated when client presses Ctrl+c, and I can terminate client and re-run it to connect with Server as many as times I want till Server is turned on without the first run Error.

I can also say that, Once the Server is running good, Next run will be the Error. And after that Error, the Next run will be a successful stream.

[chek this out for my server and client program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46092658/socket-programming-with-usbcam-using-python-3-4-opencv-3-2)

Comment: solution for error 2 is urgently needed - legends help me!!

Comment: @api55 help me in solving the error 1

Comment: @slawekwin I have seen ur replies regarding the above error can u help me to solve this error. plz give me detailed answer bro.